# Compute modular inverse

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

Given two positive numbers \$x\$ and \$n\$ with \$x<2^n\$, write the shortest possible function to compute \$x^{-1} \mod 2^n\$.  In other words, find \$y\$ such that \$xy=1 \mod 2^n\$.

Your function must complete in a reasonable time for at least \$n=64\$, so exhaustive search will not work.

If the inverse does not exist, you must indicate that to the caller somehow (throw an exception, return a sentinel value, etc).

If you're wondering where to start, try the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: this is going to be a single statement in some math softwares

Comment: @st0le: Right, and you wouldn't be allowed to use such a function in such systems. :-D

Comment: Exponentiation has higher precedence than modulo, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python <strike>95</strike> 89

`c` is your function. Returns 0 if there is no inverse (i.e. when x is even).

```
p=lambda x,y,m:y and p(x,y/2,m)**2*x**(y&1)%m or 1
c=lambda x,n:[0,p(x,2**n-1,2**n)][x%2]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 29 bytes

```py
lambda x,n:pow(x,2**n-1,2**n)
```

This returns 0 for even *x*. It uses Euler’s theorem, with the observation that 2^*n* − 1 is divisible by 2^(*n* − 1) − 1, via Python’s builtin fast modular exponentiation. This is plenty fast enough for *n* up to 7000 or so, where it starts taking more than about a second.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:pow(a,-1,2**b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3PCsIwDMbvfYqwUzfq2CaiDDz6Cp68tK7DQteWNP7Z09duigc/SAhffl8SZrp5tz0ETCMc4ZKsnNQgQQrVB//kUmxa0VWVKpOZgkeCOEfGRo9gjdNg3GLUkQbjegZZhPNnWCQFqHx2koEbR2LN1DFYQ7wsf1TAvOQjX@ivrV9XHQjO0t71CdFj/0cXzlP@/tBIRlldlKltYMf2a3UN2ze5vwE)

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica - 22

```
f=PowerMod[#,-1,2^#2]&
```

`f[x,n]` returns `y` with `x*y=1 mod 2^n`, otherwise `x is not invertible modulo 2^n`

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript (23 chars)

```
{:^((1${\.**2^?%}+*}:f;
```

The sentinel result for a non-existent inverse is `0`.

This is a simple application of [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem). \$x^{\varphi(2^n)} \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}\$, so \$x^{-1} \equiv x^{2^{n-1}-1} \pmod {2^n}\$

Unfortunately that's rather too big an exponential to compute directly, so we have to use a loop and do modular reduction inside the loop. The iterative step is \$x^{2^k-1} = \left(x^{2^{k-1}-1}\right)^2 \times x\$ and we have a choice of base case: either `k=1` with

```
{1\:^(@{\.**2^?%}+*}:f;
```

or `k=2` with

```
{:^((1${\.**2^?%}+*}:f;
```

---

I'm working on another approach, but the sentinel is more difficult.

The key observation is that we can build the inverse up bit by bit: if \$xy \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{k-1}}\$ then \$xy \in \{ 1, 1 + 2^{k-1} \} \pmod{2^k}\$, and if \$x\$ is odd we have \$x(y + xy-1) \equiv 1 \pmod{2^k}\$. (If you're not convinced, check the two cases separately). So we can start at any suitable base case and apply the transformation \$y' = (x+1)y - 1\$ a suitable number of times.

Since \$0x \equiv 1 \pmod {2^0}\$ we get, by induction

\$x\left(\frac{1 - (x+1)^n}{x}\right) \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}\$

where the inverse is the sum of a geometric sequence. I've shown the derivation to avoid the rabbit-out-of-a-hat effect: given this expression, it's easy to see that (given that the bracketed value is an integer, which follows from its derivation as a sum of an integer sequence) the product on the left must be in the right equivalence class if \$x+1\$ is even.

That gives the 19-char function

```
{1$)1$?@/~)2@?%}:f;
```

which gives correct answers for inputs which have an inverse. However, it's not so simple when \$x\$ is even. One potentially interesting option I've found is to add `x&1` rather than `1`.

```
{1$.1&+1$?@/~)2@?%}:f;
```

This seems to give sentinel values of either \$0\$ or \$2^{n-1}\$, but I haven't yet proved that.

Taking that one step further, we can ensure a sentinel of \$0\$ for even numbers by changing the expression \$1 - (x+1)^n\$ into \$1 - 1^n\$:

```
{1$.1&*)1$?@/~)2@?%}:f;
```

That ties with the direct application of Euler's theorem for code length, but is going to have worse performance for large \$n\$. If we take the arguments the other way round, as `n x f`, we can save one character and get to **22 chars**:

```
{..1&*)2$?\/~)2@?%}:f;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby - 88 characters

Use the function `f`.

```
def e a,b;a%b==0?[0,1]:(x,y=e(b,a%b);[y,x-(y*(a/b))])end
def f x,n;e(x,2**n)[0]*(x%2)end
```

Simply the recursive function from the linked wiki page, returns 0 on error.

Comment: You can save some characters by inlining e: `(e=->a,b{...})[x,2**n][0]`. Can also save a character by testing `a%b<1` instead of `a%b==0`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 42 bytes

```hs
_!1=1
x!n|r<-x!div(n+1)2=(2-r*x)*r`mod`2^n
```

Using an [algorithm based on Hensel’s lemma](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6626) that doubles the number of digits in every iteration, this runs in under a second for *n* up to about 30 *million*!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
.^Et^2Q^2
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.%5EEt%5E2Q%5E2&input=9%0A5&debug=0)

Takes input in reverse order. Or, 9 bytes too: `.^EtK^2QK`.

## Explanation

```
.^Et^2Q^2  - Full program.

.^         - Pow function. The same in Python (pow).
  E        - The second input.
    ^2Q    - And 2 ^ first input.
   t       - Decremented.
       ^2  - And 2 ^ first input again.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
2*æi@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99I6/CyTIf/1kqHlzvoP2pa4/7/f7ShgY6CaayOQrQ5gjYyADMMwCwA)

Takes input with \$n\$ first and \$x\$ second, returns \$0\$ if no such inverse exists. The Footer in the TIO link reverses the input for you and formats the test cases.

### How it works

```
2*æi@ - Main link. Takes n on the left and x on the right
2*    - Yield 2*n
  æi@ - Modular inverse of x, modulo 2*n, or if none exists, 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

## GAP, 39 bytes

```GAP
f:=function(x,n)return 1/x mod 2^n;end;
```

`f(x,n)` returns the inverse of `x` modulo `2^n` and gives an error message

```
Error, ModRat: for <r>/<s> mod <n>, <s>/gcd(<r>,<s>) and <n> must be coprime
```

if no inverse exists.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <strike>10</strike> 9 bytes

```
2\?:q(?q%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlvrGDy3yjG3qpQw75Q9f9/AA)

A port of Mr. XCoder's solution, to GS. Stack manipulation is a little messy, could probably be done with a little tomfoolery. Takes in input as X N.

V 1.1 : Improved stack manip, it sucks a lot less now.

```
2\?:q(?q% #Multiplicative Inverse
2\        #Move "2" to the second pos on the stack. X 2 N
  ?       #Exponentiate. X 2^N
   :q     #Remember, q is 2^N.
     (    #Decrement. X 2^N-1
      ?   #Exponentiate. X^(2^N-1)
       q? #Mod by 2^N.

# X^([2^N] -1) % 2^N is the multiplicative inverse, since
# X^([2^N] -1)*X = X^(2^N)
# which is 1 mod 2^N if X and 2^N are coprime.
```

If there is no M.I., it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>77</s> 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,n,b=1,i=1:n and f(x,n-1,b-(b&i)*~-x,i+i)or b%i
```

Outgolfed all you snek users (except for the `pow(x, -1, 2**n)` cheapshots) with nothing but pure algorithm.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7tboMgFP3vU9y4rMWONgo2oIkPAxPbu1gkwrb2z17dgWbJUpL7weFwznGPcJ0sl25elqEb1U33Cu7UUt1VFLuqtaBsDwOJ2LGi@kj0DovDz/FO8Q2LaQb9igve3DQH8A@fvYBbJYGfJKCHj08fYIi8cDWQm7sz78HnWUJGtAbQpm8nH3q0bQbxKAoaOrgpR9AGutJO3o0YSFGsDDfHB/In1kJOQe2qNaibvomiMSk7HHSKl9spRJMvMwfUo8mpsX23p3CZQgv7TS9Eu4Ek3@2OQ4I6KLdA/yyfxDa6Gb15ZoZiqUo4Z2ItVmaiTL3hsmaiil3WggvBZFrPMg4m2VnUgjWsKXkt05S8qaUAyfgv) (Only uses Python 3.8 for comparison against `pow(a,-1,2**n)`)

Ungolfed version:

```python
def func(value, shift, acc = 1, mask = 1):
    if value != 0:
        return func(value, shift - 1, acc - (acc & mask) * (value - 1), mask << 1)
    else:
        return acc & (mask - 1)
```

Or, as a loop with size hacks removed:

```python
def func(value, exponent):
    value -= 1
    acc = 1
    for i in range(exponent):
        if acc & (1 << i):
            acc -= value << i
    return acc & ((1 << i) - 1)
```

### Explanation

The function is a lambda called `f`. It takes two positive integers, and returns either the multiplicative modular inverse or zero.

You may be wondering what the heck is going on. This uses a different, faster, and smaller algorithm for modular inverse for powers of 2 instead of the Euclidian approach.

I'm not going to go too far into the details of *why* it works, as it is really complex and explained better by others. <sub>Translation: even I don't fully understand it.</sub>

This set of algorithms is explained [here on algassert](https://algassert.com/post/1709) with a related algorithm explained [here on Crypto SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/how-to-determine-the-multiplicative-inverse-modulo-64-or-other-power-of-two)  with some interesting papers linked.

This algorithm actually uses no true multiplication (just shifts), the multiplication is just a shortcut for size.

This naturally returns `0` for even numbers, as the *odd* subtraction (we start with `x - 1`) causes a chain reaction of trailing with `0b0`, which, when masked off, turns the result to zero. No need for a manual sentinel.

```python
0000 0001 - 0000 1101 -> 1111 0010
1111 0010 - 0001 1010 -> 1110 0000
```