# Compute the inverse of an integer modulo 100000000003

Tags: code-golf, math, abstract-algebra, restricted-time

The task is the following. Given  an integer `x` (such that `x` modulo `100000000003` is not equal to `0`) presented to your code in any way you find convenient, output another integer `y < 100000000003` so that `(x * y) mod 100000000003 = 1`.

You code must take less than 30 minutes to run on a standard desktop machine for *any* input `x` such that `|x| < 2^40`.

**Test cases**

Input: 400000001. Output: 65991902837

Input: 4000000001. Output: 68181818185

Input: 2. Output: 50000000002

Input: 50000000002. Output: 2.

Input: 1000000. Output: 33333300001

**Restrictions**

You may not use any libraries or builtin functions that perform modulo arithmetic (or this inverse operation).  This means you can't even do `a % b` without implementing `%` yourself. You can use all other non-modulo arithmetic builtin functions however.

**Similar question**

This is similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215/compute-modular-inverse?rq=1) although hopefully different enough to still be of interest.

Comment: So a-(a/b)*b is fine?

Comment: @immibis That looks fine.

Comment: tag: restricted code?

Comment: I notice you don't have any restriction that `y<100000000003`. I see at least one answer that could be shortened by dropping a final modulo...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I was definitely expecting y<100000000003.

Comment: What's special about `100000000003`? (just wondering)

Comment: @Lembik In that case, could you mention that requirement that y<100000000003 in the question?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere It is the first twelve-digit prime number?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It believe it is.

Comment: Do the restrictions disallow use of python's `pow` operator's 3rd argument? https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#pow

Comment: @bendi Yes they do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Pyth, 24 bytes

```
L-b*/bJ+3^T11Jy*uy^GT11Q
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L-b%2a%2FbJ%2B3%5ET11Jy%2auy%5EGT11Q&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A1000000%0A50000000002&debug=0)

This uses the fact that a^(p-2) mod p = a^-1 mod p.

First, I manually reimplement modulus, for the specific case of mod 100000000003. I use the formula `a mod b = a - (a/b)*b`, where `/` is floored division. I generate the modulus with `10^11 + 3`, using the code `+3^T11`, then save it in `J`, then use this and the above formula to calculate b mod 100000000003 with `-b*/bJ+3^T11J`. This function is defined as `y` with `L`.

Next, I start with the input, then take it to the tenth power and reduce mod 100000000003, and repeat this 11 times. `y^GT` is the code executed in each step, and `uy^GT11Q` runs it 11 times starting with the input.

Now I have `Q^(10^11) mod 10^11 + 3`, and I want `Q^(10^11 + 1) mod 10^11 + 3`, so I multiply by the input with `*`, reduce it mod 100000000003 with `y` one last time, and output.

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: I am guessing it's too late for me to tighten  up the test cases....

Comment: @Lembik I'd do it anyways, but opinions may vary. It's your challenge, make it work the way you want it to.

Comment: The way the question is written, it is possible you could drop the final reduction, although I asked for a clarification whether a result <100000000003 is required.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>118</strike> <strike>113</strike> <strike>105</strike> 101 bytes

Inspired from [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129721/31975).

*-12 from Ørjan Johansen*

```hs
p=10^11+3
k b=((p-2)?b)b 1
r x=x-div x p*p
(e?b)s a|e==0=a|1<2=(div e 2?b$r$s*s)$last$a:[r$a*s|odd e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclLDoIwFAXQOau4gw5ahITWmfHJClwBonkNTSRAbVpiGLD3@jnT8@Q0uXnOOZBu7lofjsUES1KG2qjWKgtdRGy01cP4xoZQhkK6byTw7oga4l2fDclfO5jWiihSmZSYOa2CT10UXKb9NQxwfV549CAsHK4PyJtHfUGIo18hfYUJXil0ptLNX58/)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

A rewrite of [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129731/31975). While fast enough for the test vector, this solution is too slow for other inputs.

```hs
s x=until(\t->t-t`div`x*x==0)(+(10^11+3))1`div`x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NclBCsIwEEbhq/zLiU0gU3GZ3sATWGsDCgbToTSj5PbpovhWH7x3LJ9Xzq0V1PAVTZlGdYM6nZ/pN9dTDcEb6oj9xNydjeFjtCUmQcAS1@sDNArcgHVLoiCxKBBjcOvtxf/rLR@4tx0)

Comment: Awesome! I like the exponentiation by squaring approach.

Comment: The shortest solution would be something like [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8DW0AAOjLmKFCpsK3RTMssUKhQKtAq4coD8Io2KOI0CXSNNzf@5iZl5CrYKuYkFvvEKGjF5Crp2CgVFmXklChp5OgrZCnmamgrRRjpQI2P/AwA "Haskell – Try It Online") but I don't think its performance is acceptable ...

Comment: (1) It's shorter to make `g` an operator `(e?b)a s|...` (2) If you switch `a` and `s` then you can make `!` a *non*-operator and inline `y` into it. (3) You can get rid of the expensive `where` by a `last` trick, at the cost of duplicating `z`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpLDoMgFEbhuav4BwzAaiJ01vTWFXQF9pFLJKlRKQHTOHDv9HWm53twGt005RxINzetd/tihCUpQ21Ua5WFLiJWWut@eGFFKEMh3Wck8OaINEXBZdr00ZD8EgfTWhFFKpMSE6dF8KH7m2ffw13zzIMHYeZwvkNePOoTQhz8AukrjPBKoTOVbn5d8xs "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Now those are nice tricks!

Comment: Oh, and `|e==0=a` gets rid of that pesky duplication.

Comment: Well spotted, updated the solution.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 22 bytes

```
∧10^₁₁+₃;İ≜N&;.×-₁~×N∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HHckODuEdNjUCk/aip2frIhkedc/zUrPUOT9cFitUdnu4HVPP/v9H/KAA)

This took about 10 minutes for `1000000` with a slightly different (and longer) version of the code which was exactly two times faster (checked only positive values of `İ` instead of both positive and negatives). Therefore this should take about 20 minutes to complete for that input.

#### Explanation

We simply describe that `Input × Output  - 1 = 100000000003 × an integer`, and let constraint arithmetic find `Output` for us.

```
∧10^₁₁+₃                   100000000003
        ;İ≜N               N = [100000000003, an integer (0, then 1, then -1, then 2, etc.)]
            &;.×           Input × Output…
                -₁         … - 1…
                  ~×N∧     … = the product of the elements of N
```

We technically do not need the explicit labeling `≜`, however if we do not use it, `~×` will not check the case `N = [100000000003,1]` (because it's often useless), meaning that this will be very slow for input `2` for example because it will need to find the second smallest integer instead of the first.

Comment: Wow, I never would have expected constraint arithmetic to pull that off. Awesome!

Comment: @isaacg The speed of this is unfortunately completely dependent on the value of `İ`, so this is still pretty slow for big products.

Comment: Updated the question. Does your code always take less than 30 minutes?

Answer (score 6):

## Python, <s>53</s> <s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>58</s> <s>53</s> 49 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to orlp
-2 bytes thanks to officialaimm
-4 bytes thanks to Felipe Nardi Batist
-3 bytes thanks to isaacg 
-1 byte thanks to Ørjan Johansen
-2 bytes thanks to Federico Poloni

```
x=input()
t=1
while t-t/x*x:t+=3+10**11
print t/x
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8I2M6@gtERDk6vE1pCrPCMzJ1WhRLdEv0KrwqpE29ZY29BAS8vQkKugKDOvRAEo/v@/oQEIQCkA)

It took me ~30 minutes to figure this one out.  My solution is to start with the first number that will mod to 1.  This number is 1. If its divisible by x, then y is that number divided by x. If not, add 10000000003 to this number to find the second number which mod 1000000003 will equal 1 and repeat.

Comment: The first number that will mod to 1 is 1...

Comment: @orlp lol thanks.  That saved me 2 bytes :)

Comment: Interesting, on TIO this is fast for all the test cases but a bit random keyboard banging gave me `421385994` which times out.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Good sleuthing.

Comment: Why not write `b=3+10**11`?

Comment: I really like this algorithm, but I can't upvote because of the unnecessary `y=0`, and more importantly the fact that both the input and output code are missing.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clear it should not to be too slow for any input values. Apologies for the late change.

Comment: If you need `b` only once, why not hardcoding it?

Comment: The OP has [relaxed the input/output requirements](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129716/compute-the-inverse-of-an-integer-modulo-100000000003?noredirect=1#comment320268_129716).  You can write a function that returns an integer, instead of actually printing.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think that would be 3 bytes longer.

Comment: Shouldn't the `//` be a `/`?

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>153</s> <s>143</s> 141 bytes

Inspired by [this answer from math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67199).

A recursive function based on the Euclidean algorithm.

```js
f=(n,d=(F=Math.floor,m=1e11+3,a=1,c=n,b=F(m/n),k=m-b*n,n>1))=>k>1&d?(e=F(c/k),a+=e*b,c-=e*k,f(n,c>1&&(e=F(k/c),k-=e*c,b+=e*a,1))):a+d*(m-a-b)
```

Modulo is implemented by computing:

```
quotient = Math.floor(a / b);
remainder = a - b * quotient;
```

Because the quotient is also needed, doing it that way does actually make some sense.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

f=(n,d=(F=Math.floor,m=1e11+3,a=1,c=n,b=F(m/n),k=m-b*n,n>1))=>k>1&d?(e=F(c/k),a+=e*b,c-=e*k,f(n,c>1&&(e=F(k/c),k-=e*c,b+=e*a,1))):a+d*(m-a-b)

console.log(f(2))
console.log(f(50000000002))
console.log(f(1000000))
```

Comment: You only need 64 bit flooring in the last occurence so you can replace the other ones with 0|x/y and remove the declaration

Answer (score 5):

## C++11 (GCC/Clang, Linux), <s>104</s> 102 bytes

```cpp
using T=__int128_t;T m=1e11+3;T f(T a,T r=1,T n=m-2){return n?f(a*a-a*a/m*m,n&1?r*a-r*a/m*m:r,n/2):r;}
```

https://ideone.com/gp41rW

Ungolfed, based on Euler's theorem and binary exponentation.

```cpp
using T=__int128_t;
T m=1e11+3;
T f(T a,T r=1,T n=m-2){
    if(n){
        if(n & 1){
            return f(a * a - a * a / m * m, r * a - r * a / m * m, n / 2);
        }
        return f(a * a - a * a / m * m, r, n / 2);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: ISO C++ only requires `long` to be at least 32-bit, so it can't necessarily hold `1e11 + 3`.  It's 32-bit on x86-64 Windows.  `long` is a 64-bit type on x86-64 Linux (and other OSes that use the SystemV ABI), though.  So to be fully portable, you'd need to use `long long`, which is [guaranteed to be at least 64-bit since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: `__int128_t` doesn't seem to be standard C++, it seems to be a gcc extension, it would be cool if you'd state this as a language (C++11 + gcc).

Comment: This is not supposed to be a C++ experts site, I hoped no one will notice.

Comment: @PeterCordes Code golf doesn't need to be portable or even well-formed, it just needs to work on one implementation.

Comment: @aschepler: I know, which is why I said "you *would* need".  I thought it was useful to point out which platform it would/wouldn't work on, in case anyone tried it and ran into trouble.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
x/.FindInstance[x#==k(10^11+3)+1,{x,k},Integers]&
```

Comment: How long does this take to run?

Comment: Less than 0.001s on my computer (for case 2^40-1)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 71 bytes

```php
for(;($r=bcdiv(bcadd(bcmul(++$i,1e11+3),1),$argn,9))!=$o=$r^0;);echo$o;
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e543565d82bcc273c4e6ae6ded5a91db9e290fd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 58 bytes

Uses isaacg's application of Fermat's little theorem for now while I finish timing the brute-force solution.

```ruby
->n,x=10**11+3{i=n;11.times{i**=10;i-=i/x*x};i*=n;i-i/x*x}
```

Current brute force version, which is 47 bytes but <s>might be</s> *is* too slow:

```ruby
->n,x=10**11+3{(1..x).find{|i|i*=n;i-i/x*x==1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cuT6fC1tBAS8vQUNu4OtM2z9rQUK8kMze1uDpTSwsoY52pa5upX6FVUWudqQWUztSF8P4XKKRFp6eWFOuV5Mdnxv43NAADQwA)