# Modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: code-golf, math, number, number-theory, abstract-algebra

Your task is to given two integer numbers, `a` and `b` calculate the modular multiplicative inverse of a modulo b, if it exists.

The modular inverse of `a` modulo `b` is a number `c` such that `ac ≡ 1 (mod b)`. This number is unique modulo `b` for any pair of `a` and `b`. It exists only if the greatest common divisor of `a` and `b` is `1`.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) for modular multiplicative inverse can be consulted if you require more information about the topic.

### Input and Output

Input is given as either two integers or a list of two integers. Your program should output either a single number, the modular multiplicative inverse that is in the interval `0 < c < b`, or a value indicating there is no inverse. The value can be anything, except a number in the range `(0,b)`, and may also be an exception. The value should however be the same for cases in which there is no inverse.

`0 < a < b` can be assumed

### Rules

- The program should finish at some point, and should solve each test case in less than 60 seconds
- Standard loopholes apply

### Test cases

Test cases below are given in the format, `a, b -> output`

```
1, 2 -> 1
3, 6 -> Does not exist
7, 87 -> 25
25, 87 -> 7
2, 91 -> 46
13, 91 -> Does not exist
19, 1212393831 -> 701912218
31, 73714876143 -> 45180085378
3, 73714876143 -> Does not exist
```

## Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest code for each language wins.

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129716/compute-the-inverse-of-an-integer-modulo-100000000003) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215/compute-modular-inverse?rq=1) are similar questions, but both ask for specific situations.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13760/72350)

Comment: Can our output be empty in case there is no such value?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, but in that case it would need to be empty for all cases in which there is no such value

Comment: It follows from Fermat's Little Theorem that the multiplicative inverse of a, if it exists, can be computed efficiently as a^(phi(b)-1) mod b, where phi is Euler's totient function: phi(p0^k0 * p1^k1 * ...) = (p0-1) * p0^(k0-1) * (p1-1) * p1^(k1-1) * ...  Not saying it leads to shorter code :)

Comment: Can we output a [optional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) type?  I'm assuming we can but I just wanted to check.

Comment: can I take as input [a,-1,b] ?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy Taking additional input is generally disallowed.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yes but I would beat mathematica's built in which is generally great!

Comment: I count six answers that seem to be brute forcing, and unlikely to run all test cases in 60 seconds (some of them give a stack or memory error first).

Comment: @ngn : You've conflated Fermat's Little Theorem (FLT) with Euler's improvement to it.  Fermat did not know about the Euler phi function.  Further, FLT and Euler's improvement only apply if gcd(a,b) = 1.  Finally, in the form you have written it, "a^(\phi(b)-1) mod b" is congruent to 1, not a^(-1).  To get a^(-1), use a^(\phi(b)-2) mod b.

Comment: @EricTowers Euler's is a consequence. Regarding "gcd(a,b)=1" - I did say "if it [the inverse] exists". Are you sure about phi(b)-2?

Comment: @ngn : Hmm...  Seems you got me turned around.  It's a^(b **-2**) = a^(-1) mod p in *Fermat's* theorem and a^(phi(b) **-1**) = a^(-1) mod p in Euler's.

Comment: @EricTowers Looks correct now, assuming by "p" you mean "b=p, where p is prime". I admit it would have been more proper, though just as true, to quote Euler's theorem (which is the generalisation to multiple prime factors) instead of Fermat's Little.

Comment: 60 seconds on which machine?

Comment: @totallyhuman Reasonable normal machine

Comment: So at least @Mr.Xcoder claims that his brute force solution (in Python) *does* run in less than 60 seconds on a normal machine - barely. Which is exactly what you'd want to avoid in choosing a non-scoring time limit.

Comment: Why limit the algorithm for just positive results and arguments, when during the computation one see values can be negative, the same the result,and that algorithm it is for all integers (negative positive zero)?

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

Obligatory Mathematica [builtin](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ModularInverse.html):

```
ModularInverse
```

It's a function that takes two arguments (`a` and `b`), and returns the inverse of a mod b if it exists. If not, it returns the error `ModularInverse: a is not invertible modulo b.`.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> <s>73</s> <s>62</s> 61 bytes

Returns `false` if the inverse does not exist.

It uses the extended Euclidean algorithm and solves all test cases almost instantly.

```js
f=(a,b,c=!(n=b),d=1)=>a?f(b%a,a,d,c-(b-b%a)/a*d):b<2&&(c+n)%n
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(a,b,c=!(n=b),d=1)=>a?f(b%a,a,d,c-(b-b%a)/a*d):b<2&&(c+n)%n

console.log(f(1, 2)) // -> 1
console.log(f(3, 6)) // -> Does not exist
console.log(f(7, 87)) // -> 25
console.log(f(25, 87)) // -> 7
console.log(f(2, 91)) // -> 46
console.log(f(13, 91)) // -> Does not exist
console.log(f(19, 1212393831)) // -> 701912218
console.log(f(31, 73714876143)) // -> 45180085378
console.log(f(3, 73714876143)) // -> Does not exist
```

Comment: Why is it not possible to write the name of function f, as in                             f(c,a,b=0,d=1,n=a)=>c?f(a%c,c,d,b-(a-a%c)/c*d,n):a<2&&(b+n)%n ?

Comment: @RosLup `f(x,y)` is always parsed as a function call, except if it is explicitly preceded by the `function` keyword. An anonymous arrow function, on the other hand, is declared as `(x,y)=>something` and `f=(x,y)=>something` assigns the function to the `f` variable.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:a==1or-~b*f(-b%a,a)/a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCsJADETvfkVAhFZSJEltdoX9mCyyKGhbSi9e/PW1Bytrj@8NzMz4mm9Dzzmn8LBnvBoYxouFQMPUvOMxVU08GFp9sjxO936GVBECQ73brywI3cIrKoLTgvm8FQieygKSr/kJj0BMLF6clIEs2ypKrdOOWtm8@EvyBw)

Recursive function that gives `True` for `print f(1,2)`, which I believe to be acceptable, and errors for invalid inputs.

We are trying to find \$x\$ in \$a\cdot x\equiv 1\pmod{b}\$.

This can be written as \$a\cdot x-1=k\cdot b\$ where \$k\$ is an integer.

Taking \$\mod{a}\$ of this gives \$-1\equiv k\cdot b\pmod{a}\$. Moving the minus gives \$-k\cdot b\equiv1\pmod{a}\$, where we have to solve for \$k\$.

Seeing how it resembles the initial scenario, allow us to recurse to solve for \$k\$ by calling the function with \$f(-b\%a,a)\$ (works because Python gives positive values for modulo with a negative argument).

The program recurses for until \$a\$ becomes 1, which only happens if the original \$a\$ and \$b\$ are coprime to each other (ie there exists a multiplicative inverse), or ends in an error caused by division by 0.

This value of \$k\$ can be substituted in the equation \$a\cdot x-1=k\cdot b\$ to give \$x\$ as \$\frac{k\cdot b+1}{a}\$.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
æi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wssz/h5frP2paE/n/f7S5joV5rE60sY4ZkIRyjEyhtI6lIZAyNAbRAA)

This uses a builtin for modular inverse, and returns 0 for no modular inverse.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
R×%⁸’¬T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o8HTVR407HjXMPLQm5P/h5Q76j5rWRP7/H22uY2EeqxNtrGMGJKEcI1MorWNpCKQMjUE0AA)

Outputs empty set (represented as empty string) on no modular inverse. Runs out of memory on TIO for the largest test-cases, but should work given enough memory.

**How it Works**

```
R×%⁸’¬T  
R        Generate range of b
 ×       Multiply each by a
  %⁸     Mod each by b
    ’    Decrement (Map 1 to 0 and all else to truthy)
     ¬   Logical NOT
      T  Get the index of the truthy element.
```

If you want to work for larger test-cases, try this (relatively ungolfed) version, which requires much time rather than memory:

### Jelly, 9 bytes

```
×⁴%³’¬ø1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//w5figbQlwrPigJnCrMO4MSP///84N/83)

**How it Works**

```
×⁴%³’¬ø1#
        #   Get the first
      ø1      one integer
            which meets:
×⁴            When multiplied by a
  %³          And modulo-d by b
    ’         Decrement
     ¬        Is falsy
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 18 bytes

```
PowerMod[#,-1,#2]&
```

**input**

> [31, 73714876143]

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [numbers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numbers/numbers.pdf), 15 bytes

```r
numbers::modinv
```

returns `NA` for those `a` without inverses mod `b`.

[R-Fiddle to try it!](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=l01inC73&version=1)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes (non-competing)

This will fail on very large `b` since it actually creates a vector of size `32*b` bits.

```r
function(a,b)which((1:b*a)%%b==1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJszwjMzlDQ8PQKkkrUVNVNcnW1lDzf5qGuY6FueZ/AA)

Returns `integer(0)` (an empty list) for those `a` without inverses mod `b`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

Takes the inputs in reverse order. Outputs `-1` for no match. Craps out as the bigger integer gets larger.

```
Ç*V%UÃb1
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xypWJVXDYjE=&input=ODcsNw==)

- Saved 1 byte thanks to ETH pointing out an errant, and very obvious, space.

Comment: The test input `73714876143,31` seems to produce an out-of-memory error on Firefox (and to crash Chromium). I don't think this is a valid answer.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I clearly pointed out that fact in my solution. We can assume infinite memory for the purposes of code golf so the memory issues and crashes do not invalidate this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the memory issues also make it impossible to tell whether your code would actually solve the test cases in 60 seconds as stipulated by the challenge. I suspect it would not, even if there was sufficient memory available to make it not crash, but without a computer that can actually run the program for that long there's no way to tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>51</s> <s>49</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 49 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to officialaimm</sup>
<sup>-1 byte thanks to Shaggy</sup>

```python
a,b=input()
i=a<2
while(a*i%b-1)*b%a:i+=1
print+i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyTYzr6C0REOTK9M20caIqzwjMydVI1ErUzVJ11BTK0k10SpT29aQq6AoM69EO/P/f3MdC3MA)

Prints `0` when there is no solution.

Comment: Outputs `0` for `a=1` and `b=2`; from the test cases, it should output `1`.

Comment: [As a recursive algo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIVEnSSfT1sAqSRXIzktRSNTKVE1StDUEsdM0wLLahpr5RQqZ/wuKMvNKNNI0zHUszDU1/5vrKFiYKwAA)

Comment: As Shaggy pointed out, fails for `2, 1`

Comment: @Shaggy should work now

Comment: This fails to return an answer in 60 seconds (on TIO) for the input `31,73714876143`.

Comment: This goes into infinite loop for the input `4, 6`, since there is no inverse, but `b%a != 0`. (For inverse to exist, it's not enough that `b` is not divisible by `a`, you need them to be coprime.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 10 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to [@Jakube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29577/jakube)*.

```
xm%*szdQQ1
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xm%25%2aszdQQ1&input=3%0A6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=87%0A7%0A%0A6%0A3%0A%0A87%0A25%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

Returns `-1` for no multiplicative inverse.

#### Code Breakdown

```
xm%*szdQQ1      Let Q be the first input.
 m      Q       This maps over [0 ... Q) with a variable d.
   *szd         Now d is multiplied by the evaluated second input.
  %    Q        Now the remained modulo Q is retrieved.
x        1      Then, the first index of 1 is retrieved from that mapping.
```

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
KEhfq1%*QTKSK
```

Throws an exception in case no multiplicative inverse exists.

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=KEhfq1%25%2aQTKSK&input=3%0A6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=7%0A87%0A%0A3%0A6%0A%0A25%0A87%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
Iq1iQKEfq1%*QTK
```

This adds lots of bytes for handling the case where no such number exists. The program can be shortened significantly if that case would not need to be handled:

```
fq1%*QTK
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Iq1iQKEfq1%25%2aQTK&input=7%0A87&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=7%0A87%0A%0A3%0A6%0A%0A25%0A87%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)**

Comment: 2 bytes saved with `KExm%*QdKK1`

Comment: Or 3 bytes if you swap the order of inputs: `xm%*szdQQ1`

Comment: @Jakube Thanks a lot, editing!

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @Cowsquack I've added a completely primitive code breakdown but rn I don't have time to include a complete explanation.  Hopefully it is clear enough for now but I'll try to add a more complete explanation soon.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder no rush, I wondered how the algorithm worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [gmpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy/1.17), 23 bytes

I don't think it can get any shorter in Python.

```python
gmpy.invert
import gmpy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPz23oFIvM68staiEKzO3IL@oRAEk9L@gKDOvRCNNw1zHwlxT8z8A) (won't work if you do not have gmpy installed)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[c for c in range(b)if-~c*a%b==1][0]+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqOlkhLb9IIVkhM0@hKDEvPVUjSTMzTbcuWStRNcnW1jA22iBW2/B/QVFmXolGmoa5joW5piYXjGukY2mIxDXWMdPU/A8A)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:[c for c in range(1,b+1)if c*a%b==1][0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqOlkhLb9IIVkhM0@hKDEvPVXDUCdJ21AzM00hWStRNcnW1jA22iD2f0FRZl6JRpqGuY6FuaYmF4xrpGNpiMQ11jHT1PwPAA)

This throws `IndexError: list index out of range` in case there is no modular multiplicative inverse, as it is allowed by the rules.

Comment: This fails to return a result for the input `31,73714876143` in 60 seconds (on TIO).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Seems to finish in 56 seconds on my machine (Macbook Pro '15)

Answer (score 2):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 6 bytes

**Code**

```
invmod
```

**Explanation**

`invmod` is a 8th word that calculates the value of the inverse of `a`, modulo `b`. It returns `null` on overflow or other errors.

**Usage and test cases**

```
ok> 1 2 invmod .
1
ok> 3 6 invmod .
null
ok> 7 87 invmod .
25
ok> 25 87 invmod .
7
ok> 2 91 invmod .
46
ok> 13 91 invmod .
null
ok> 19 1212393831 invmod .
701912218
ok> 31 73714876143 invmod .
45180085378
ok> 3 73714876143 invmod .
null
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 11 bytes

```
a->b->1/a%b
```

Throws an error when there is no inverse.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9R1y5J185QP1E16X9BUWZeiUaahrGhpoa5sbmhiYW5maGJsabmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 28 bytes

```
4 :'(1=x+.y)*x y&|@^<:5 p:y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCoNAFAV7T/GqqBEi7//Vv7sqeJCQFCES0sTShdx9I1aBYWCKeee8YIpwiGXFaWsuqT5vSKfvfBtjhzWmsiiej9cHd0E1LG19BSFQ9DB4g3SHEQjq4QAKRYN6JXZMjc5bT6f79lc5/wA)

Uses [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler.27s_theorem). Returns 0 if the inverse does not exist.

### Explanation

```
4 :'(1=x+.y)*x y&|@^<:5 p:y'  Input: a (LHS), b (RHS)
4 :'                       '  Define an explicit dyad - this is to use the special
                              form `m&|@^` to perform modular exponentiation
                          y   Get b
                      5 p:    Euler totient
                    <:        Decrement
             x                Get a
                   ^          Exponentiate
               y&|@             Modulo b
       x+.y                   GCD of a and b
     1=                       Equals 1
            *                 Multiply
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48 110</s> 104 bytes

```c
#define f(a,b)g(a,b,!b,1,b)
long g(a,b,c,d,n)long a,b,c,d,n;{a=a?g(b%a,a,d,c-(b-b%a)/a*d):!--b*(c+n)%n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1NDoIwEIX3nKJgSFqcRociBYnxAhzBTVt@QoLVGHeEsyNo4ooyi0ne@2beM7w1Zpp2Vd10tiYNVaBZu2zwNeAsvP5hW/KzDFRg2df4y2JQF3VtqQ4VqNkwnGo@C3ZQUcXOPuc6omZvWWiLcbqrzlI2eM9XZ98NDcK@r242gLkZIWaEFWtIQOpCEjLpYvFpC0KOLoZiAwrA4zLu7xwIxhiLXGTCHYNApJCYZDLFRJSlu2/lbpw@)

This should work with all inputs (that fit within a long) within 60 seconds.

Edit. I'm already abusing the `n` variable so I might as well assume that gcc puts the first assignment in `%rax`.

Comment: Alas, this gives wrong results even for fairly small inputs due to integer overflow inside the loop. For example, `f(3,1000001)` returns 717, which is obviously nonsense (the correct answer is 333334). Also, even if this bug was fixed by using a wider integer type, this brute-force approach would certainly time out for some of the larger test cases given in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 115 bytes

```c
#define L long long
L g(L a,L b,L c,L d){return a?g(b%a,a,d-b/a*c,c):b-1?0:d;}L f(L a,L b){return(g(a,b,1,0)+b)%b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLbsIwEDzHX7ECIdllQ@OYEsAt/ECkHntoOdjOo5bSUIVwivzrTU1E2iL1sI9Z73pmbROWxvT9NMsLW@eQQnWsy8GRFEqagsIUtDfjLWNdk7fnpga1L6meKVSYhfpe3Rk0bKtDvo@2mXQpFOPkOEFLqlAjx4jNNZtp6fqprU11znJ4PLWZPS7ed4TYuoUPZWvKoCPBqW3OpoXuV5S/FLQEB@3rAZ4uPUEHHCEGh0MuEFZjniCskxHEDzcIYcNHwMUN2iDwmMdiI9bipyo8SSISvlwnK74Uf@j@qUYIETgSOEmC4tgAvaxlvd5IeuH2sFAS7Hw@7Bh8Nv60oJNZVWUIFw/hbohv9QSv/deo0b/sbYUxT@K5rh8TSeL6L1NUqjz14XPchy@qqr4B)

Extended Euclidean algorithm, recursive version

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 119 bytes

```c
long long f(a,b,c,d,t,n)long long a,b,c,d,t,n;{for(c=1,d=0,n=b;a;a=t)t=d-b/a*c,d=c,c=t,t=b%a,b=a;return b-1?0:(d+n)%n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFNb8IwDD23v8JiQmpXlzUNo2VZ2E/YkcPGIR@URcrCVMKp6l9fFyrYQNrF9nux9Z4dle@UGga7dzsYQ5MIlKhQo0eX/vFXLOuafZsoTlDzAh2XTDDBfeq5zuWDuA9tXKHiHj2X0zDIBWu3/tg6kDl5KZ4Snbl06lg/3Bmn7FFv4fngtdnPPlZxbJyHT2FckkIXRwffHpWHDq6tgGTQg3/bAD/1RB0QhBJ6HGuKsLjUFUJdXUD5eIMQluQCCL1BSwRSkpIuaU1/WRpEKlqReV0tyJxeyf3DFggF9HHUszgK54LktJYJfgsWjJvNTDAwWTbuGH214bVJJlNrNcIpQr4a87ub4Ln/nCWGP7pl0jSIBK3zkQsW98O3aqzYHYb8tRzytbD2Bw)

Extended Euclidean algorithm, iterative version

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 <strike>38</strike> bytes

```apl
{⌈/i×1=⍵|(i←⍳⍵)×⍵|⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRT4d@5uHphraPerfWaGQ@apvwqHczkK15eDpI5FHvrtr/aWDRvkd9Uz39H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIMV/hsqpCkYcRkDSTMucyBpYc5lZAqlgZSlIZehMYQGAA)

Explanation:

```apl
                   ⍵|⍺} ⍝ Get ⍺ mod ⍵
             (i←⍳⍵)×     ⍝ Multiply the result by all numbers up to ⍵
          ⍵|            ⍝ Take result mod ⍵
     i×1=                ⍝ Find all numbers (1,⍵) where the mod is 1
{⌈/                      ⍝ And take the largest
```

Much thanks to Adam in the APL Orchard chatroom for the help with this one!

Formula obtained from [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/)

First iteration:

```apl
{((⍵|⍺),⍵){+/⌈/⍵×1=(¯1↑⍺)|⍵×⊃⍺}⍳⍵}
```

Comment: what about larger tests? the challenge says: "_The program should finish at some point, and should solve each test case in less than 60 seconds_"

Comment: we usually count 1 char = 1 byte in apl

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 22 bytes

```
lambda a,b:pow(a,-1,b)
```

Obligatory Python 3.8+ builtin. Outputs the result, or gives the error `ValueError: base is not invertible for the given modulus` if there is no result.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwFET3niJ0ZeC7@Pm1SQruvEXtItEWC5qENKA9fUyli27mMTMwE5b09I5UiHm83PLLvO3DMAO2Df5zNHBCsDyPPq4ZmxzrOgTRQ0fQFJWgZIE4bwSNBUgbNaBAQZoUrZ4QJEmslWywpv/I3vftgbEUlzbEyaVybmFclfOSD9/7ENKuqq5@mJnzqVTTnCqefw)

**Explanation:**

To quote the [Python 3.8 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes):

> For integers, the three-argument form of the [pow()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#pow) function now
> permits the exponent to be negative in the case where the base is
> relatively prime to the modulus. It then computes a modular inverse to
> the base when the exponent is -1, and a suitable power of that inverse
> for other negative exponents. For example, to compute the [modular
> multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of 38 modulo 137, write:
>
> ```
> >>> pow(38, -1, 137)
> 119
> >>> 119 * 38 % 137
> 1
> ```
>
> Modular inverses arise in the solution of [linear Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation). For example, to find integer solutions for `4258 + 147 = 369`, first rewrite as `4258 ≡ 369 (mod 147)` then solve:
>
> ```
> >>> x = 369 * pow(4258, -1, 147) % 147
> y = (4258 * x - 369) // -147
> 4258 * x + 147 * y
> 369
> ```
>
> (Contributed by Mark Dickinson in [bpo-36027](https://bugs.python.org/issue36027).)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt], 1 byte

```
ɯ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5Pr//y0NuQyNAQ)

Takes inputs in the order `b a` (on separate lines). Outputs `None` if there is no such multiplicate inverse. Gotta love built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + sympy, 74 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
def f(a,m):i,_,g=numbers.igcdex(a,m);return g==1and i%m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BCoMwGIPvPkUuA5WfQVtn1eGTjDHcrK6HtlIrzKd3KkN2ykcCCRnm8HaWL0vnncE4m2GGNoPzIY1a1aGLGzJJpelBfW0n81R@POv@1arPnly9CpO36OuaNbaFPpklqDGMqHGLGYEnhFgQ8k0loZAb8MtBhJJtwMRBJYFxxkUpCrE7Yi2SQrKskDnLxK/y37lHUec8NLTFvl9h8NqG9UCqk@UL)

[Taken from Jelly source code.](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/jelly.py#L467-L469)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>42</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

Outputs `false` for no match. Will throw a overflow error as the second number gets to be too large.

```
x=>y=>(g=z=>x*z%y==1?z:z<y&&g(++z))(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.*

```python
f=lambda a,b,i=1:i*a%b==1and i or i<b and f(a,b,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv/Yq5CEndy6ZotbhfIh4SanBB09Lm4tdHU8HTvIHhzfzOjym5UqI8/SuMHp4CqfCgrd8FEfZphGJaoJeAWqLZJnu2Jd/XvEJwNUxwlmA6wrFmTzj1FdzhT4QzV@DuR7emidULTdhMA@ZFU/4@tGrLBw)

Outputs `False` on no solution and errors out as `b` gets larger.

### Embedded TIO

I'm just testing out iframes in Stack Snippets and they work absolutely fantastic.

```css
html,body{height:100%;}iframe{height:100%;width:100%;border:none;}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv/Yq5CEndy6ZotbhfIh4SanBB09Lm4tdHU8HTvIHhzfzOjym5UqI8/SuMHp4CqfCgrd8FEfZphGJaoJeAWqLZJnu2Jd/XvEJwNUxwlmA6wrFmTzj1FdzhT4QzV@DuR7emidULTdhMA@ZFU/4@tGrLBw"></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm not certain this works, can't `i*a%b` be `0`?

Comment: Fails with "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error for input `(31,73714876143)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 45 bytes

```
f(x:PI,y:PI):NNI==(gcd(x,y)=1=>invmod(x,y);0)
```

0 for error else return z with x*z Mod y =1

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
²%³
⁴Ç⁹Ð¡x⁸
ÆṪ’BṚçL$P%³×gỊ¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9qZWxsef//wrIlwrMK4oG0w4figbnDkMKheOKBuArDhuG5quKAmULhuZrDp0wkUCXCs8OXZ@G7isKl////NzM3MTQ4NzYxNDP/MzE)

Uses Euler's theorem with modular exponentiation. Since Jelly doesn't have a builtin to perform modular exponentiation, it had to be implemented, and it took most of the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 99 bytes

```
w(a,b,x,u)==(a=0=>(b*b=1=>b*x;0);w(b rem a,a,u,x-u*(b quo a)));h(a,b)==(b=0=>0;(b+w(a,b,0,1))rem b)
```

it use the function h(); h(a,b) return 0 if error [not exist inverse] otherwise
it return the z such that a*z mod b = 1
This would be ok even if arguments are negative...

this would be the general egcd() function that retunr a list of int (so they can be negative too)

```
egcd(aa:INT,bb:INT):List INT==
   x:=u:=-1   -- because the type is INT
   (a,b,x,u):=(aa,bb,0,1)
   repeat
      a=0=>break
      (q,r):=(b quo a, b rem a)
      (b,a,x,u):=(a,r,u,x-u*q)
   [b,x, (b-x*aa)quo bb]
```

this is how use it

```
(7) -> h(31,73714876143)
   (7)  45180085378
                                                    Type: PositiveInteger
```

i find the base algo in internet from https://pastebin.com/A13ybryc